# Why do researchers needs computing power outside the university?

Tags: research-process

A layman wants to help people in science. How useful would it be for him to join for some [BOINC](https://boinc.berkeley.edu) project? I somehow think that many researchers gets computing power from their universities so I am unsure why do we need [BOINC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Open_Infrastructure_for_Network_Computing).

Comment: What is BOINC? This question needs much more context.

Comment: The utility to you is for you to decide. To the researchers, there is utility in the outreach to involve people, as well as many problem can be broken up and parceled out to fairly low horsepower computers.

Answer (score 3):

1. Boinc can supply much more computational power than a university can or wants to supply.
2. Idealistic aspect: We all have computers at home with (from a historical perspective) tremendous computing power and they do nothing for most of the time. Why not use them productively for research?

Now you could argue about power consumption etc., but I think the general idea is clear.

Comment: BOINC-type computing is good for simple tasks that need to be repeated millions of times  but anything that is really RAM-hungry (beyond typical RAM of a PC) cannot be done in this way. RAM-hungry computations do represent a significant fraction of the serious computing power.

Answer (score 3):

Question 1: *Why do researchers needs computing power outside the university?*

Projects such as BONIC and [Open Science Grid](https://opensciencegrid.org/) were initially created to serve single purposes where individual universities and government labs could not do all of their own computing.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Science_Grid_Consortium):

> The Open Science Grid was created in order to facilitate data analysis from the Large Hadron Collider, and about 70% of its 300,000 computing-hours per day are dedicated to the analysis of data from particle colliders

From The [BIONIC homepage](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/):

> The open source infrastructure “BOINC” developed in the Space Sciences Laboratory at the University of California at Berkeley for volunteer and grid computing was developed to search data obtained with radio telescopes for signals from extraterrestrial life (SETI@home).

Now, both grid systems are open to other researchers as well because the infrastructure exists and other scientists have needs as well.

Also, one program for high-throughput computing is [HTCondor](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/), which has the name "HT" for High-throughput (added after a [lawsuit about software names](https://lists.cs.wisc.edu/archive/htcondor-users/2012-October/msg00110.shtml)) and "Condor" because it originally scavenged unused resources like a condor scavenges carrion.

Question 2: *A layman wants to help people in science. How useful would it be for him to join for some BOINC project?*

Historically, very important. Now, less important because I suspect most of their computing comes for large contributors such as universities. Looking at the [BIONIC homepage](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/), their help section has sections for `Translate`, `Test`, `Document` and `Publicize`.
If you have any skills to help with these, my guess is that those would help the project more than a single desktop computer.